# Does ros_control support limit switches

Tags: ros, microcontroller, joint, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I've just get my robots arms running with ros_control.

My robot read joints position using incremental (quadrature) encoder. These sensor doesn't provide absolute position but only relative to the initial position.

So to set the real position I just sent to joint a small amount of effort and waiting to hit a limit switch, then I set the real position value.

I was wondering if ros_control has something (service or interface) to support initialization processes like this described above, before load the controller, or even better to be part of the load service call. Do you think that is a hardware related issue so it must handled from my node after all?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213152/does-ros_control-support-limit-switches/) by [elsp1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/22168/elsp1991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: no, there is no support for limit switches in `ros_control`, but I'd argue that it is also not something that should be there (as something like *initialisation of a robot* to me seems like a higher-level behaviour).

---

At the moment `ros_control` is mostly concerned with providing an efficient and re-usable way to setup a (relatively simple) controller architecture that is able to interface with a ROS node graph. Most (if not all) default controllers operate at the joint-space level, and the package can be said 'to live' at the (or at least very near to) *Controller* layer (in a 3T architecture, just an example).

It would make more sense to me to make something like *initialisation* a higher-level behaviour, perhaps part of a larger overall [statemachine](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) (again, just an example, there are others) that encodes the *Executive* part of your architecture. At start-up, your application then always passes through the initialisation (sub)states first, before accepting any other requests for execution of behaviours. That initialisation phase would then interact with `ros_control` to switch controllers to the appropriate types at the appropriate times, search for the limit switches and setup your encoders properly.

`ros_control` (and more specifically, the `hardware_interface` part of it) could perhaps be used to implement an interface to your limit switch hardware, similar to the [joint_state_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_controller) (which isn't a controller at all, it's a sensor interface, publishing `JointState` msgs). Whether that is something that makes sense depends on preference and how you've setup the rest of your system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0